# UseState variable not updating after setting it within a function - React Native

Tags: react-native, use-state

Howcome when i setURL(value) or setURL(val) it doesnt actually set the state?

Only when I press the upload button a second time it sets the state correctly..

First time run:

[image: First time run]

My initialized state:

```
const [URL, setURL] = useState();
```

The function to get the downloadURL:

```
await getDownloadURL(fileRef).then((val)=>{
  console.log("From function: "+val)
  var value = val;
  setURL(value)

}).catch((error)=>{
  Alert.alert(error.message);
});
```

Upload button function:

[image]

My code:

```js
const AddPost = () => {

const [isEnabled, setIsEnabled] = useState(false);
const toggleSwitch = () => setIsEnabled(previousState => !previousState);
const [Color, setColor] = useState('')
const [Desc, setDesc]= useState('');
const [location, setlocation] = useState('');
const navigation = useNavigation()

const [image, setImage] = useState(null);
const [URI, setURI] = useState(Result);
const [Result, setResult] = useState();
const [URL, setURL] = useState();
const [uploading, setUploading] = useState(false);


const usersCollectionRef = collection(db, "Posts");

  const createPost = async () => 
  {
  setUploading(true); 
  let url = await uploadImageAsync(URI); 
  console.log("from upload btn: "+URL)
  await addDoc(usersCollectionRef, { username: auth.currentUser?.email, Colour: Color, Injured: value2, Type: value3, Collar: isEnabled ? 'Yes' : 'No', Welfare: value4, status: value, Description: Desc, picture: URL, location: location })
  Alert.alert("Successfully uploaded!");
  navigation.navigate('MainScreen');
  setUploading(false);
  };
  

  const TakeImage = async () => {
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
      quality: 0.6,
    });


    if (!result.cancelled) {
      setImage(result.uri);
      setURI(result.uri);
    }
  };


  const BrowseImage = async () => {
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
      allowsEditing: true,
      quality: 0.6,
    });

    console.log(result);

    if (!result.cancelled) {
      
      setImage(result.uri);
      setURI(result.uri);
      
    }
  };

  const uploadImageAsync =async(uri)=> {
    
    const blob = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.onload = function () {
        resolve(xhr.response);
      };
      xhr.onerror = function (e) {
        console.log(e);
        reject(new TypeError("Network request failed"));
      };
      xhr.responseType = "blob";
      xhr.open("GET", uri, true);
      xhr.send(null);
    });
  
    const fileRef = ref(getStorage(), uuid.v4());
    const result = await uploadBytes(fileRef, blob);
    
    let url = await getDownloadURL(fileRef).then((val)=>{
      console.log("From function: "+val)
        setURL(val);
        return val;

    }).catch((error)=>{
      Alert.alert(error.message);
    });

    return url;
    
    
  }
```

Comment: when and where is getDownloadURL function called?

Comment: @this.arjun Just edited it now. Its called when I click on a button.

Comment: so you're updating the state URL and using it inside the same function call. Updating state is an async function so it won't reflect. So you should return the uri from getDownloadURL and store it in a temp variable and use it.

Comment: @this.arjun I dont quite understand, sorry! Do you mean like this                            
 return await getDownloadURL(fileRef).then((val)=>{
      console.log("From function: "+val)
        setURL(val);

    }).catch((error)=>{
      Alert.alert(error.message);
    });

Comment: wait i'll post an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since updating state is an asynchronous method so the state will not get updated immediately. You'll have to work around like this -

```
 const uploadImageAsync =async(uri)=> {
    // rest of your code
    let url = await getDownloadURL(fileRef).then((val)=>{
      console.log("From function: "+val)
        setURL(val);
        return val;

    }).catch((error)=>{
      Alert.alert(error.message);
    });

    return url;
    
  }
```

And then in your onPress function:-

```
    const createPost = async () => {
      let url = await  uploadImageAsync(URI);
      // Rest of your code
    }
```

Comment: Still producing the same result. Ive done it eaxtly how you suggested.

Comment: can you update the code here as well?

Comment: Yea, just updated the post now including it. Thanks.

Comment: you'll also have to change from URL to url everywhere inside the createPost as well. eg- picture: url